# One-to-many mapping inside struct

Tags: solidity, contract-development, struct

I have two structs:

```
struct A{
    uint bid;
    mapping(uint => B[]) BMap; //bid - index for struct B

}

struct B{
    uint cid;
}

mapping(uint => A[]) AMap;
```

How can we push and fetch 'cid' in struct B?

Comment: I'm not sure but may be this answer can give you an idea about what you want to achieve. https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/77357/38516